# Admin dashboard

Tags: magento2, admin

when I click all customers menu page not loading fully and am getting some error

https://prnt.sc/26kip40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug error in this way.

1. Disable `all third party` extensions and check that issue resolve or not.
2. If that resolve, then enable extension one by one, and check from enabling which extension error occurs.
3. Try to resolve the error from that extension.

Comment: Thanks, will check

Comment: If answer help, then upvote and accept as solution. so this will help other in community.

Comment: Yes, already did